# How to persuade someone into leaving constructive comments, or none at all?

Tags: discussion, comments

Just the other day I stumbled upon a question that wasn't really answerable in its current form, and the (close-)voting on it indicated that. Some people left some constructive questions in comments as well on why the question was unclear and what could be improved.

Then this comment was posted:

> I have so many questions about your question I don't even know where to start.

Yes, very funny and very snarky, but not constructive at all. A comment pointing out that a question is bad, must contain pointers to improve the question, or not be posted at all, according to [Be Nice.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice):

> If you don't have time to say something politely, just leave it for someone who does.

And [Privileges > Comment Everywhere](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment):

> - Request clarification from the author;
> - Leave constructive criticism that guides the author in improving the post;

To me, it was obvious that that comment was neither polite, nor constructive, nor asking for any kind of clarification. Saying "I have so many questions" does not tell the OP what part of their question is unclear, and only adds insult to injury. Perhaps the commenter doesn't speak English very well, or they don't know how to work with the tagged language, making it their very own problem and not the OP's.

So I asked that user, in the same comment chain:

> @user please don't add snarky comments that don't actually add anything. :)

Which unleashed an upvoted shitstorm in comments against me that now *I* was the one not being constructive.

I know I can flag as "not constructive" (I did) and leave it at that, but that won't teach that user anything: they'll just notice their comment has disappeared, if they even do notice, and that'll be that. In that sense, flagging as "not constructive" is not constructive in and of itself.

So: how can I enlighten a user that they may not be as constructive or funny as they think they are?

Comment: Just flag, eventually leave your own constructive comment and move on.

Comment: Frankly, calling someone's comment unconstructive _is_ unconstructive. Unelss you're explaining _why_ said comment isn't constructive, which would make your unconstructive comment constructive.

Comment: @Cerbrus: I just flagged your comment for being too difficult to parse.

Comment: @Cerberus Actually, explaining why the comment isn't constructive isn't constructive, since constructive comments are comments which are constructive *to the original post*, not to other unconstructive comments.

Comment: The comment isn't really snarky, and I don't see how its funny at all.  It's not constructive in that, as you've said, it contains no actionable information, so it's *noise*, but it's not *insulting* or "not nice", any more than it would be if he'd actually listed out a whole pile of questions that the author would need to answer.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> *"How can I enlighten a user that they may not be as constructive or funny as they think they are?"*

That's not your responsibility.

Flag the comment and move on. If the user is repeatedly flagged for comments like these, moderators will notice and have a little chat with said user.

Comment: I'm not trying to play moderator, I don't have time for that. :) The comment was upvoted by three people, indicating some people found it funny or constructive. This may encourage that user to continue posting such comments. A moderator will not go and have a chat after one flag. So you're saying we should let the situation derail before any action, if any, ever, will be taken?

Comment: I'd argue that debating the constructiveness of a comment is a from of derailment already. _"let the situation derail before any action, if any, ever, will be taken?"_ You make the issue sound more hazardous than it usually is, but yes, a single comment like that really doesn't warrant intervention. If it becomes a pattern, then a mod should have a chat with the user. That's why the flags are important, to register the pattern.

Comment: @CodeCaster this is pretty much what I'd answer. Note that there's also an auto flag for "n" many comments flagged as certain types within a certain time which is fed by people flagging comments so we can see any potential trends. If it's an occasional snarky comment here and there - everyone has an off day/not in a good mood now and then - we'll just delete and move on. If it's repeated behaviour, then yes, we do reach out with advice to the user about how they should use commenting constructively.

Comment: @JonClements - It is nice to hear that there is some sort of automated system applied here, but it needs to be stronger in my opinion. The system should probably take some tips from the recividism system and reduce comments to repeat offenders for some time frame to only their posts. Further, it would be nice to see it weighted heavier if the repeated behavior is towards the same user.

Answer (score 2):

You can flag comments as non-constructive. Don't try and tell the commentor that they aren't being helpful.

[image]

If you can leave constructive comments yourself then do so, otherwise flag and move on.

Comment: _"I know I can flag as "not constructive""_ <-- he's aware that's an option ;-)

Comment: @Cerbrus ah, I must have missed that part. I guess I'm saying essentially the same as you though. I'll leave this up anyway in case someone else doesn't know what flags there are.

Comment: Aye, Fair enough!